# Canonical SSH 'public key' answer?

Tags: discussion

Is there a need for a question (or set of questions) and answers around SSH publickey refusal queries?

For stuff like,

- [Why do I get "Permission denied (publickey)" when trying to SSH from local Ubuntu to a Amazon EC2 server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39733/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-publickey-when-trying-to-ssh-from-local-ubunt)
- [Permission denied (publickey) when trying to ssh into an ec2 machine (-v details included)](https://serverfault.com/questions/178495/permission-denied-publickey-when-trying-to-ssh-into-an-ec2-machine-v-details)
- [ssh error with publickey for normal user](https://serverfault.com/questions/364904/ssh-error-with-publickey-for-normal-user)
- [Permission denied (publickey) error](https://serverfault.com/questions/181280/permission-denied-publickey-error)
- [Not able to do ssh(without asking passowrd) to remote System using Authentication Keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/397495/not-able-to-do-sshwithout-asking-passowrd-to-remote-system-using-authenticatio)
- [EC2 instance always ask me to enter passphrase for the pem during connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/379938/ec2-instance-always-ask-me-to-enter-passphrase-for-the-pem-during-connection)

I was thinking along the lines of setting up key pairs, permissions, remembering to ssh in as the right user, using -v -v to get more diagnostics, settings in the sshd_config file, etc.

However, thinking about it further, I wondered how much of that is on-topic for ServerFault, rather than SuperUser or Linux/UNIX?  Just thought I'd gather some opinions.

Comment: Don't forget to make it clear that the permissions are critical, which I suspect is the problem in most of those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I find a lot of SSH *usage* questions to be more SU-worthy. However, it is the glue that holds together a lot of our networks so it's one of those gray area things.

Given that, I do see value in a question/answer pair that covers the major bases in one concise set. It shouldn't have an encyclopedia of how public-key works, but address the core cause(es) and how errors manifest; the deep-dive can happen after those two.

Comment: Any answer should probably address the proper use of `ssh-agent` as well.

Comment: IMHO if the problem is you can't SSH into a server, you don't know yet if it's a server problem or a user problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it seems like a reasonably popular idea - how do I / we make it happen?  Do we just wait for an opportune question or does someone write a new one, or do we go and find an old one?